# Who can call __get__, __set__ and __del__?

Tags: python, descriptor

This is my code. I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
class a:
    def __get__(self):
        return 'xxx'
    def aa(self):
        print 'aaaa'

b=a()
print b.get('aa')
```

Please try to answer in code, because my English is not very good. Thank you.

```
class HideX(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self.__x

    def set_x(self, x):
        self.__x = x+10

    x = property(get_x, set_x)

inst = HideX(20)
print inst.x
inst.x = 30
print inst.x
```

Comment: What should happen when you run this code? What is the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `obj.get`, but there is no get function in `class A`, hence error,
either rename `__get__` to `get` or if you by chance are trying to use descriptors do something like this

```
class A(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, klass):
        print "__get__", obj, klass
        return 'xxx'

class X(object):
    a = A()

x=X()
print x.a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read a bit more on [Descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) before you try to use them.

Comment: What's the difference between your twos' last lines?

Comment: Huh? I thought it read 'print a.get('aa')'. I'll change my answer

Comment: It did read `print a.get('aa')` in the beginning, but the OP fixed it.